# Layer still in map after running arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, arcpy

I'm trying to run a script that removes a group layer from a set of map documents, the code runs and the correct zone to be deleted prints out, However, when I check my map documents, the layer is still there. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I have so far:

```
import arcpy
import os

PATH2 = r"C:\Users\Daimon Nurse\Desktop\DFMPROJECT"
arcpy.env.workspace = PATH2
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True

for file in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    filePath = os.path.join(PATH2,file)
    MapDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(filePath)
    lyrList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(MapDoc,"Zones","")
    for Lyr in lyrList:
        for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(MapDoc):
            print Lyr  
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,Lyr)
```

Comment: Hey Daimon, this is the sixth question you've asked in the last day or two, and you've only accepted answers for two of these. You'll be more likely to get useful answers when you accept answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the map after changes.

```
MapDoc.save ()
```